# How can I play the tapes I'm getting?

Tags: metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain

I am receiving tapes at the end of every mission like "Ocelot's Briefing" etc. How do I play them? In the first level I have no iDroid and in the later levels I don't know how to play them.

Answer (score 4):

Open up your iDroid and there will be a **Cassette Tapes** menu item under the **Missions** tab. In here, all of your acquired tapes will be listed.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to them via the [mobile app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.konami.mgsvtppapp) as well. This is useful if you are bored while cooking dinner...